# MainActivity Syntax error on token invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java, android, android-intent, syntax-error

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void  onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
         findViewById(R.id.button2);
         Button Ciao=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);       
         Ciao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         Intent openPage=(MainActivity.this,Page1.class); 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                startActivity(openPage); 
            }



         });
 }
```

Where is the problem? Eclipse says the error is in the "," in `Intent openPage=(MainActivity.this,Page1.class);`
But I think the code is correct... Have you some ideas? 
Naturally I clean the project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating a new Intent. Better yet, do it in the onClick. There's no reason to create the Intent ahead of time, it'd work better in the `onClick`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent openPage=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page1.class);
    startActivity(openPage);
}
```